# Comparison of Baseband simulation results and experimental results at Passband

Tags: dsp-core

Consider that I have simulated a communication system at baseband and would implement the same on hardware but using a carrier at 2.4GHz(Passband conversion).

Would it make sense to compare the simulated results at baseband and the results from the experiment at passband? Or should the simulation also be performed at Passband frequency and then compare the experimental results with the simulated results at Passband?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time there is no good reason to simulate at passband, as long as you simulate the signal's and the channel's low-pass representation. Furthermore, assuming that you're using a modern radio such as an SDR, most of the hardware is operating at baseband anyway -- frequency up- and down-conversion are performed as close to the antenna as is feasible.

Also, be aware that, most likely, your simulation and experimental results will be hard to compare directly. For example, it is hard to find exactly what the SNR at the receiver is; you'll have to estimate it. Also, it's hard to determine the exact channel parameters. Other factors are non-linearities in the power amplifiers, synchronization imperfections, etcetera.

Comment: If I have a 2 tx and 1 rx setup, with the signals from the 2 tx summed at the rx(MISO), can I assume safely that even at passband the signals from the 2 tx are added similar to the two signals being added at the baseband frequency?

Comment: Yes, that is a safe assumption.